# TypeError 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__' when drawing a 3D-plot

Tags: python, numpy, plot, plt

Below is my fuction:

```
def draw3D(draw_tick, matrixArray):
    print "Drawing tick = %d\n" % draw_tick
    matrix = matrixArray[draw_tick - 450]
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    X = np.arange(-40, 40, 1)
    Y = np.arange(-40, 40, 1)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
    Z = np.matrix[Y+40][X+40]
    surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1,cmap=cm.coolwarm,linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
    ax.set_zlim(-1.01, 1.01)

    ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
    ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

    fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

I want to draw a 3D plot with variables x,y,z.

```
TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

This error points to the line of Z:

```
Z = np.matrix[Y+40][X+40]
```

I want to store the value of that point (of matrix) into Z

Can anyone help me to solve it?

Lots of thanks!

Update of my question:
I have a matrixArray containing hundreds of matrices of 81*81.
I want to draw a plot of one matrix in that array.
So I declared:

```
matrix= matrixArray[draw_tick - 450]
```

to decide the particular one. Then I want to put the matrix location as X & Y, and put the value of the location as Z. But I want my X and Y be from -40 to +40, that is why I'm adding 40 to the two axis.

Comment: `np.matrix` is a type object, which you cannot index. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: I just want to give Z the value of that point. So then how to I do?

Comment: Did you mean to use `matrix` instead of `np.matrix`?

Comment: @YaofengWang -- you're acting like `X+40` and `Y+40` are scalars -- they aren't.  They're arrays which are constructed by adding 40 to every element of the arrays returned by `np.meshgrid`.  So it's very unclear how you're trying to give `Z` a value of a specific point when you don't have a specific point...

Answer (score 0):

[numpy.matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html#numpy-matrix) is a class (and classes in Python are objects that are instances of `type`), and you are trying to access it as if it was a nested array. You probably want the value in `matrix` instead.

Comment: numpy.matrix is actually a class, not a function

Answer (score 0):

From calling help(np.matrix) we get:

```
 |  Examples
 |  --------
 |  >>> a = np.matrix('1 2; 3 4')
 |  >>> print a
 |  [[1 2]
 |   [3 4]]
 |  
 |  >>> np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
 |  matrix([[1, 2],
 |          [3, 4]])
 |
```

You must create an instance of the matrix. Perhaps you want to do:

```
Z = np.matrix(YOUR_ndarray_AS_ARGUMENT)
```

Comment: But I want Z be the value in that specific point. How should I store matrix[Y+40][X+40] then?